# How do I recalculate a repo's indices with the jfrog cli?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I sometimes have to manually recalculate repo indices: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CalculateHelmChartIndex

I already use the jfrog cli. This seems like something that would be an easy command with the jfrog cli but I do not see it in the docs: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note the CLI is capable of running **any** cURL REST API against Artifactory. For more information, please refer to [this documentation page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-RunningcUrl) or use below example:

$ jf rt curl -XPOST /api/helm/$REPO_NAME/reindex --server-id $SERVER_ID

Comment: So there is no specific command to do this yet beyond making a REST call? It makes it a little easier, but It also requires the `curl` exec to be installed locally as a dependency: "The command expects the cUrl client to be included in the PATH". Would be nice if there was a builtin command that had no external dependencies.

Comment: Agreed. This answer defeats the use of `jf`.